# R ggplot: How to format x-axis such that first label is different to the subsequent

Tags: r, ggplot2, format

I noticed that the Financial Times (FT) has nicely formatted graphs and there are elements that I would like to use in my own graphs.

One element is that when they show data where the horizontal x-axis is "year" they show the full year for the first label but then truncate the subsequent labels just to show the last two digits. So for example:

```
2015   16   17   18   19  20
```

I would be grateful if someone was able to assist with how I can do this using `ggplot2` in `R`

Thank you

Comment: `+ scale_x_**(breaks = 2015:2020, labels = c(2015, 16:20))`

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much Axeman.